# Shift to left when I enter {} in JSX code - VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm seeing this super annoying behavior for quite a while now. When I enter {} in JSX (React code) the line I'm writing on shifts either to the left or right. The behavior happens when I close curly braces. Here are two screenshots. The difference is the insertion of the closing }.

[image]

Closing

[image]

I'm not really sure how to find the setting causing this. I've tried deleting some extensions and tried to find. Does someone know how to disable this?

Comment: Mine doesn't do that. Can you share a screenshot of your installed extensions? Also your settings.json file could help too

Comment: I only have a few extensions aside from themes (I have a lot of themes - that makes the screenshot hard). I have no extension installed that relates to JavaScript, React or JSX. Just Jupiter Notebooks, Python, XML, and Markdown support.

Comment: compare your settings with https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings default settings

Comment: Maybe someone else has had this problem before and can help. Comparing all settings would be my last resort.

Comment: Possibly the same question as [Line shifts to the start when inserting {} into some JSX in React](/q/63472816/11107541).